# ld: building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64

Tags: gcc, ld

I have this strange issue where creating / using a static library works in my Ubuntu VM but not on macOS:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ./dist/libXXXX.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
```

Command to create the static library is:

```
ar rcs libtest.a obj1.o obj2.o ...
```

Compiler invocation:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra main.c -L./dist -lXXXX -o main
```

Searching on google didn't yield any usable results except for this (maybe) related question on SO:

[Possible related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603882/go-build-building-for-macos-x86-64-but-attempting-to-link-with-file-built-for-ma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at my script that automatically creates the static library I've found the culprit:

For some reason my tool created object files for header files (resulting in files like `header.h.o`).

Removing those fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old post and you found your fix, but let me post this here for anyone else who runs into this problem for whom these answers don't provide a solution.

You might be using two different toolchains unknowingly, one from Apple (installed via Xcode) and one from GNU (installed via Home-brew or MacPorts). If you type `ranlib --version` and see version info showing that `ranlib` is GNU, this is likely the case.

Make sure that `/usr/bin` comes in your `$PATH` **before** `/usr/local/bin` and `/opt/local/bin`. When you run `which -a ranlib`, the **first** result in the list should be `/usr/bin/ranlib`. Same for `which -a ar`-- the first result should be `/usr/bin/ar`. If it is not so, you need to fix your `$PATH`.

Once you fix your path and clean your project, try building again and things should work.

Comment: That's good! I can't verify it because as you correctly stated I was able to solve my problem. However your effort is appreciated, so here have my upvote :)

Comment: In my case, it is not working. BTW, ranlib is uniquely from xcode.. BTW, it is an Apple M1 machine. But I have been using 'arch -x86_64 make' to compile and in this case leads to 'ld: building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64'

Comment: I am suffering from the same issue as @guanglei

Answer (score 2):

The issue was solved when I directly put those object files rather than gathering them into a static library, i.e.,
`gcc -g -Wall -Wextra main.c obj1.o obj2.o -o main`

After that, I got many warnings like `ld: warning: object file (obj1.o) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.14)`, but it is a warning, and the object is linked, so the problem is solved.

The root cause is that some library passes `-mmacosx-version-min=10.14` to gcc, so the object file is built for 10.14, but my macos is now 11.0.

If you want to make things work, try **directly using object files rather than creating a static library**.

If you want to resolve all the warnings, find ``-mmacosx-version-min` and comment it.